# Фильтр таблицы WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, datagrid, фильтрация

Здравствуйте, помогите создать фильтр для DataGrid.XSD, всю голову сломал, находишь примеры, а они настолько запутаны, что очень сложно что-то понять. Спасибо.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Таблица x:Key="Таблица"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="таблицаViewSource" Source="{Binding _Таблица, Source={StaticResource Таблица}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource таблицаViewSource}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Фильтр таблицы" Width="107" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,3" />
    <TextBox x:Name="TXT" Margin="112,6,267,7" Background="Yellow" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="_ТаблицаDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,10,107,74" Grid.Row="1" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="номерColumn" Binding="{Binding Номер}" Header="Номер" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="имяColumn" Binding="{Binding Имя}" Header="Имя" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="фамилияColumn" Binding="{Binding Фамилия}" Header="Фамилия" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, как-то так, подпишитесь на `TextChanged`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TXT" ... TextChanged="TXT_TextChanged"/>
```

И в подписчике:

```
private void TXT_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Берем наш CollectionViewSource, к которому выполнена привязка в DataGrid
    var cvs = (CollectionViewSource)Resources["таблицаViewSource"];
    // И устанавливаем ему предикат-фильтр
    cvs.View.Filter = o => ((Item)o).Имя.StartsWith(TXT.Text);
}
```

Здесь вместо `Item` напишите имя своего типа, который представляет одну строку таблицы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте, прошу прощения, а вот - Имя своего типа  ITEM это КЛАСС?

Comment: Да, это класс..

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, приходиться создавать Класс чтобы работал фильтр, но у меня уже есть таблица которая создана из набора данных.XSD, а как мне в неё установить фильтр. Спасибо.

Comment: Что за таблица? DataTable? Или что?

Comment: Я её создал из:  Данные - Набор Данных - DataSet1.xsd

Comment: Покажите класс `Таблица`

Comment: private Таблица.СотрудникиRow ДобавитьСотрудников(int Номер, string Имя, string Фамилия)
        {
            return this.НаборДанных.Сотрудники.AddСотрудникиRow(Номер, Имя, Фамилия);
        }  Она у меня вот таким способом записана

Comment: Это не то. Ищите `class Таблица` и покажите его содержимое

Comment: А как его найти, если его надо было создавать в ручную ,то соответственно его не создавал

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76324/discussion-between--nop-and-).